# Choosing a following speed to prevent overtaking

Tags: ios, math, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

In my game characters would swim from the lower end of the screen to the top end of the device screen.

There will be four or more swimming lanes, with multiple characters inside. Each of the characters has an individual travel speed, and I don't want the characters to overlap or overtake.

I have attached a sketch to show the rough game layout. 
[image]

I'm struggling with how to calculate the speed of the newly spawned character (O1) so that it won't overlap or overtake the previous character (O2) in the same swimming lane.

```
# variables available to calculate the character speed
- O2 = origin of the previous character
- O1 = origin of the new character
- D  = distance between character 1 and 2
- S2 = the speed of the previous character

# unknown values
- S1 = the speed new character?

# example
O2 = 10, 100
O1 = 10, 10  
D = O2.height - O1.height
S2 = 10 (10 pixels per frame)  


S1 = ?????
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just be any S1 ≤ S2?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - they travel different distances.  The key is that the time the second one takes (==distance/rate) must be less than time the first one takes.

Comment: @JoshCaswell No, S1 can be greater then S2 if there's enough distance between the two swimmers (characters).

Comment: It _can_ be, but it does it _need_ to be, @LordZsolt?

Comment: Probably needs to be, since if S1 -ltoe S2, the game would appear a little monotone.

Comment: @SaschaHeld, are you looking for the _maximum_ speed for S1 that prevents overtaking?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I would. The calculate a random between minV and maxS.

Comment: @JoshCaswell i'am looking for a random speed value low enough to prevent overtaking. a preferred solution would allow a faster speed of the new character when possible without overtaking (if the distance is huge enough) to create a more dynamic feeling.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, since the distances vary, a simple way to think about it is using time.

Swimmer0 will take `time0 = distance0/speed0` seconds to swim to the end.

When Swimmer1 begins, Swimmer0 will have completed partial0 seconds of his journey, so Swimmer0 will have `(distance0/speed0)-partial0` seconds remaining.

This is the minimum time Swimmer1 must take.  So we want the rate of Swimmer1 to be:

```
speed1 < distance1 / ((distance0/speed0)-partial0)
```

to insure that Swimmer1 will finish after Swimmer0